# How to activate anti-aliasing via Emscripten

Tags: webgl, sdl, antialiasing, emscripten, asm.js

in webGL, it is possible to activate anti-aliasing on canvas-context intialization like

```
gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", { antialias: true });
```

My simple question is: how can this option be set via Emscripten C++ to asm.js compiler ? I do not ask about implementing my own antialiasing via custom shader code.

Comment: I have found the following code in the outputed .js file, which hints there are variables that might be set in some way WITHOUT editing the html/js "shell files" used for generation:
    createContext:function (canvas, useWebGL, setInModule, webGLContextAttributes)
return ctx = canvas.getContext(webglId, contextAttributes);

Answer (score 2):

In SDL you can set antialias enabled through SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS. Like this:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1); // enable MULTISAMPLE
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 2); // can be 2, 4, 8 or 16
SDL_SetVideoMode(...)
```

This native code will enable antialias for gl context. Look at library_sdl.js:

```
// in makeSurface function
var webGLContextAttributes = {
    antialias: ((SDL.glAttributes[13 /*SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS*/] != 0) && (SDL.glAttributes[14 /*SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES*/] > 1)),
    depth: (SDL.glAttributes[6 /*SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE*/] > 0),
    stencil: (SDL.glAttributes[7 /*SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE*/] > 0)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If SDL is used, as noted in another answer, you can simply call the following:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 0 or 1);
```

If GLUT is used, one must simply call `glutInitDisplayMode()` with/without `GLUT_MULTISAMPLE`.

If EGL is used, the only option is to force change the built javascript code from `_glutInitDisplayMode(146);` to `_glutInitDisplayMode(18);` as `eglCreateContext()` simply internally uses GLUT commands.